# How to inject session scope bean in interceptor using java config with Spring

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc, interceptor

I'm developping a full Spring 3.1 and servlet 3.0 application. But my interceptor has a private properties scoped as proxy:

```
public class MyInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Ressource
    private UserSession userSession;
}
```

The user session is defined as:

```
@Component 
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS) 
public class UserSession implements Serializable {
   ....
}
```

When using this user session in the interceptor, java throws a `NullPointerException` for `userSession`.

I think the problem comes from my javaconfig oriented spring configuration:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.whatever"})
@Configuration
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new MyInterceptor());
    }

    ...
}
```

The problem is that interceptor is manually instantied, so without instrumentation for the session proxy mechanism. Thus, the question is: "how can I let Spring detect and instance the scope session proxy bean in the java config of my application ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you posted works, but you aren't taking advantage of Spring's autowiring capabilities. What if you had many services or other beans to inject into your `MyInterceptor` bean.

Instead just make a `@Bean` method for your `MyInterceptor`

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.whatever"})
@Configuration
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public UserSession userSession() {
        return new UserSession();
    }

    @Bean
    public MyInterceptor myInterceptor() {
        return new MyInterceptor(); // let Spring go nuts injecting stuff
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(myInterceptor()); // will always refer to the same object returned once by myInterceptor()
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use annotation in the java config class:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.whatever"})
@Configuration
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public UserSession userSession() {
        return new UserSession();
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        MyInterceptor interceptor = new MyInterceptor();
        interceptor.setUserSession(userSession());
        registry.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    }

    ...
}
```

And you need to remove `@Scope` and `@Bean` annotation from `UserSession` class.